# Package conflict for pymeep-parallel in anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, meep

So I am trying to install pymeep-parallel through conda. I am getting all these package conflict errors.
the command I used is 
`conda create -n pmp -c chogan -c conda-forge pymeep-parallel`

My system is windows subsystem linux 1.

```
Package harminv conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> harminv
Package h5utils-parallel conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> h5utils-parallel
Package mpb conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> mpb[version='>=1.6.1|>=1.7.0']
Package scipy conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> scipy
Package matplotlib conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> matplotlib
Package mpich conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> mpich[version='3.2.*|3.2.*,>=3.2,<3.3.0a0']
Package libgdsii conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> libgdsii=0.2.dev
Package libctl conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> libctl[version='>=4.0.0|>=4.1.0|>=4.1.4']
Package h5py-parallel conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> h5py-parallel
Package gsl conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> gsl[version='2.2.*,>=2.2.1,<2.3.0a0|2.2.*|2.2.1.*']
Package python conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
Package mpi4py conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> mpi4py[version='2.0.0.*|3.0.*']
Package openmpi conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> openmpi=2.0
Package numpy conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> numpy
Package hdf5-parallel conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> hdf5-parallel
Package * conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> *[track_features=nomkl]
Package h5utils conflicts for:
pymeep-parallel -> h5utils
```

Comment: Does the recommended install command work?  `conda create -n mp -c conda-forge pymeep`

Comment: Yes, the installation for serial meep works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. Turns out the command shown is outdated. The correct way to do it is to use

`conda create -n pmp -c conda-forge pymeep=*=mpi_mpich_*`